# Discord Music Bot im Python adding a Queue

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm adding a music feature to my bot so that it can play songs from youtube. So far the bot can play one song but I want to add a queue, so that if a song is playing at the moment, the song will be added to a list. I've tried some methods already but always ended up having errors here and there so I want to know what the best way to add a queue in my case is. I've seen some people use asyncio but I don't lnow how I could use it in here. I think the last part of the script is the most important one so the code before is not significant but I still put it in. Thanks for helping me already!

```
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, keywords: str):
        song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove("song.mp3") #Removing song if old one is in directory
        except PermissionError:
            await ctx.send("`Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command.`")
            return #Can't delete because song is playing at the moment

        if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

            if not self.bot_is_connected(ctx):
                await channel.connect()  #Joining channel if it hasn't happened yet
            else:
                pass
        else:
            await ctx.send("`You are not connected to a voice channel.`")

        if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
            video = get_url(f"{keywords}")  #Getting Song URl from Youtube using an imported request
            print(video)

            voice = discord.utils.get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

           
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([video])                         #Downloading song
                meta = ydl.extract_info(video, download=False) 
                video_name = (meta["title"])

            for file in os.listdir("./"):   
                if file.endswith(".mp3"):        #Renaming the song so that it can be found by the player   
                    os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))  #Playing the song
```